# Awesomplete (type ahead) minChars

Tags: jquery

I'm playing around with awesomeplete and I'm having some issues with minChar... I don't want the autocomplete to start until at least 5 characters have been entered. 
Here is the [documentation link](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#customization).

Here is my js function.. .everything works but it starts the autocomplete on two chars.

```
    function getSpeciesList() {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/ref/taxa/ebird?cat=species,hybrid&fmt=json&locale=en_US", true);
        ajax.onload = function () {
            var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).map(function (i) { return i.comName + "<span class='deets'> " + i.sciName + "</span>"; });
            new Awesomplete(document.querySelector("#speciesList"), { list: list }, { minChars: 5, maxItems: 15 });

            $(".input-loader").css("background-image", "none");
        };
        ajax.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added it as an inline HTML attr. worked great

```
<input type="text" data-minchars="4" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" id="speciesList" class="input-loader" style="width: 600px;">
```